# i want to ingore the empty value to insert database in Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Actually, I get some data from the array where is product id is not null because every product has an id and its hidden type. I input the data price and quantity. when I input all data there is no problem but when I input only one row there is a problem because other array data is null. actually, I insert data in my database only where data is not null. here is table form

```
         <form action="{{ route('seller.product.create') }}" method="post">
                                @csrf
                                @forelse ($products as $i => $product)
                                <tr role="row" class="odd">
                                    <td>{{ $i + 1 }}</td>
                                    <td><img src="{{ asset('products/' . $product->image) }}"
                                             width="60" height="60" alt=""></td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->product_name }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ Str::limit($product->product_description, 50) }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $product->unit->name }}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="products[]" value="{{ $product->id }}" id="">

                                        <input type="number" min="0" name="quantites[]" style="width: 80px" placeholder="Ex: XXX"  id="qty">


                                    </td>
                                    <td ><input type="number" min="0" name="prices[]" style="width: 80px"  placeholder="Ex:00.00" id="price">

                                    </td>


                                </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-success">Propose</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </form>
```

here is controller code i want only data where quantity and price is not null

```
   public  function create(Request  $request){
    $products = $request->products;
    $quantities = $request->quantites;
    $prices = $request->prices;

    foreach($products as $key => $product)
    {
        $sellerpro=new SellerPropose();
        if($products[$key] && $product > 0){
            $sellerpro->product_id=$product;
            $sellerpro->price=$prices[$key];
            $sellerpro->quantity=$quantities[$key];
            $sellerpro->seller_id=Auth::user()->seller_id;
            $sellerpro->save();
        }

    }
        Session::flash('info','Your Product has been submitted!');
        return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not useful?

```
if($products[$key] && $product > 0){
    $sellerpro->product_id=$product;
    $sellerpro->price=$prices[$key];
    $sellerpro->quantity=$quantities[$key];
    $sellerpro->seller_id=Auth::user()->seller_id;
    // not save if $prices[$key] or $quantities[$key] are null
    if(!$prices[$key] == NULL && !$quantities[$key] == NULL) {
       $sellerpro->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Always explain what you did rather then just posting the code. Apart from that, it would be better to do this in the first if statement, because it is not needed to set the values on $sellerpro when you don't save them.